# Можно ли программно (VBA) создать подтаблицу в таблице?

Tags: база-данных, access, vba, office

Допустим, имеется 2 БД, которые имеют идентичные структуры, но их отличие в том, что в одной есть подтаблицы, а в другой нет.
Задача: Перенести все подтаблицы из одной БД в другую.
Подскажите, это можно сделать программно через VBA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел такой пример работы с подтаблицами:
https://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/527558-change-table-property-subdatasheet-name-via-code